# What is $\mathbb Q[x]/((x-1)^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

What is $\mathbb Q[x]/((x-1)^2)$ as a ring? Can we use the first isomorphism theorem somehow? But I am having trouble thinking of a homomorphism. What is a better way to think about this problem?

Comment: This is just a ring of polynomials of type $ax+b, a, b\in\mathbb {Q} $ with addition and multiplication modulo $(x-1)^{2}$. The structure is not a field as the polynomial $(x-1)^{2}$ is reducible. You can think of simpler but similar example like $\mathbb{Z} /9\mathbb{Z}$ which is a ring but not a field.

Comment: Since $\Bbb Q[x] = \Bbb Q[x + 1]$, your ring is isomorphic to the [dual numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number#Generalization) over $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2)$. As Paramanand says, this is the set of $a + bx$, $a,b\in\Bbb Q$, such that $(a + bx)(c + dx) = ac + (ad + bc)x$. It is a 2-dimensional $\Bbb Q$-vector space, but as a ring, the description above is probably the best you're going to do. It's not isomorphic to another ring typically encountered, and the description given is explicit enough for computations or whatever else you really need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalize: For a ring $R$ and an ideal $I$ there is a natural  surjective homomorphism of rings $R\to R/I$. In your case $R$ is a PID, and the ideal  is of the form $(b^2)$ for a $b\in R$. Clearly the image of $b$ will be a nilpotent element in the quotient ring.

Comment: So $\overline{x-1}$ will be nilpotent in $\mathbb Q[x]/((x-1)^2)$ of order $2$, but I still don't quite see how i can figure out what $\mathbb Q[x]/((x-1)^2)$ is

Comment: Describe the quotient ring as a vector space over the field of rational numbers: that is write find a basis over $\mathbf{Q}$, and for each pair of basis element find the product and express it bas a linear combination of the basis again. This would describe the multiplication inn that quotient ring

Comment: You've been given an explicit description of the elements in the ring, and told how they multiply. What more do you want? --- Indeed, you can't really ask for more, as this determines the ring! If you're hoping it is isomorphic to a *more familiar ring* you're out of luck.